# SIGSEGV error while checking cassandra session is closed or not

Tags: go, cassandra, gocql

This is the code to check gocql session is closed or not. I am using gocql.Session.Closed but getting sigsegv error on closed part when cassandra.service is down. The expected output should be to give status is down although the code is getting broken.

```
func CheckCassandraHealthCheck(cassandraCluster *gocql.Session, Host string, Port int) map[string]interface{} {
    response := make(map[string]interface{})
    response1 := make(map[string]interface{})
    response[constant.TYPE] = constant.CASSANDRATYPE
    response1[constant.HOST] = Host
    response1[constant.PORT] = Port
    log.Println("CASSANDRA Host is ", response1[constant.HOST])
    log.Println("CASSANDRA Port is ", response1[constant.PORT])

    if !cassandraCluster.Closed() {
        response[constant.STATUS] = constant.UP
        response[constant.DETAILS] = response1
        log.Println("Status of ", constant.CASSANDRASTRING, " is ", response[constant.STATUS])

        return response
    }
    response[constant.DETAILS] = response1
    response[constant.STATUS] = constant.DOWN
    log.Println("Status of ", constant.CASSANDRASTRING, " is ", response[constant.STATUS])
    return response

}



func CreateCassandraCluster(host string) (*gocql.Session, error) {
    cluster := gocql.NewCluster(host)
    cluster.ConnectTimeout = time.Second * 10
    cluster.DisableInitialHostLookup = true
    session, err := cluster.CreateSession()
    if err != nil {
        return session, err
    }
    return session, nil
}
```

getting error:-

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x378 pc=0x73bb59]

goroutine 43 [running]:
testing.tRunner.func1.2({0xac09c0, 0x1105680})
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1389 +0x24e
testing.tRunner.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1392 +0x39f
panic({0xac09c0, 0x1105680})
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:838 +0x207
github.com/gocql/gocql.(*Session).Closed(0xc0000d0310?)
    /home/srijan/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gocql/gocql@v1.1.0/session.go:483 +0x19
healthcheck/healthcheck/util.CheckCassandraHealthCheck({0xb6e8c0?, 0x0}, {0xb827e2, 0xe}, 0xd4c6d1?)
    /home/srijan/go-workspace/smt-healthcheck/healthcheck/util/CassandraHealthCheck.go:22 +0x29f
```

this is my test file

```
func TestCassandraConnection(t *testing.T) {
    expectedOutCome := make(map[string]interface{})
    detailsOutcome := make(map[string]interface{})
    expectedOutCome[constant.TYPE] = constant.CASSANDRATYPE
    detailsOutcome[constant.HOST] = "localhost"
    detailsOutcome[constant.PORT] = 9042
    expectedOutCome[constant.DETAILS] = detailsOutcome
    expectedOutCome[constant.STATUS] = constant.UP
    session, err := util.CreateCassandraCluster("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error connecting to cassandra db %+v", err)
    }
    data := models.IOModel{Components: models.Components{Type: 2, Host: "localhost", Port: 9042, Pool: session, Name: "Stage Cassandra"}, Expected: expectedOutCome}
    result := util.CheckCassandraHealthCheck(data.Components.Pool, data.Components.Host, data.Components.Port)
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(result, data.Expected) {
        t.Errorf("Cassandra HealtCheck failed expected %+v and getting result %+v", expectedOutCome, result)
    }
    session.Close()
    t.Logf("Result Obtained is %+v", result)
}
```

How to check session is closed or not if session.Closed() is giving sigsegv error?

Comment: Can you include the util.CreateCassandraCluster("localhost") code, the .Closed() call just checks a value within the session struct (protected by mutex), so interested in whats going on in that create call

Comment: can you post models.IOModel please, the error suggests instead of a *gocql.session, you are somewhere passing in a copy of the session or a mock, and not the original *gocql.session. Alternatively, change the first parameter of the call to util.CheckCassandraHealthCheck to be the session variable you already have. It's being wrapped into a struct then unwrapped to pass it in.